# Weblogic 12C sending logs to syslog

Tags: unix, log4j, weblogic12c, syslog

I want to send my weblogic log to syslog. here is what I have done so far.

1.Included following log4j.properties in managed server classpath -

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,syslog

log4j.appender.syslog=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.syslog.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.syslog.Facility=LOCAL7
log4j.appender.syslog.FacilityPrinting=false
log4j.appender.syslog.Header=true
log4j.appender.syslog.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.syslog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.syslog.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %c:%L - %m%n
```

2. added following command to managed server arguments  -

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file :<path to log4j properties file> -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger -Dweblogic.log.Log4jLoggingEnabled=true
```

3. Added  `wllog4j.jar` and `llog4j-1.2.14.jar` into domain's lib folder.

4.Then, from Admin console changed logging information by doing the following. "my_domain_name"--->Configuration--->Logging--->(Advanced options)-->Logging implementation: Log4J

Restart managed server.

I used [this](https://community.oracle.com/message/9649165?tstart=0#9647165) as refernce. But didnt get anaything in syslog(/var/log/message). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My appender was working fine, the problem was in `rsyslog.conf`. Just uncommented following properties

```
# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514
```

We were appending the messages, but the listner was abesnt, so it didnt knew what to do with it.

and from `*.debug;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages` it figures out where to redirect any (debug in this case) information to messages file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a couple items to check:

- Remove the space in DEBUG, syslog in the file
- Your last two server arguments have a space between the - and the D so make sure that wasn't just a copy and paste error in this post.
- Double check that the log files are in the actual classpath.
- Double check from a ps command, that the -D options made it correctly into the start command that was executed.
- Make sure that the managed server has a copy of the JARs correctly as they would get synchornized from admin during the restart.

Hopefully something in there will help or give an idea of what to look for.

--John

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested. Still nothing in the log.